# After registration when I go to the main page I get an error - "Trying to get property 'blog_name' of non-object"

Tags: php, laravel

after registering on my site, I get an error that says

> Trying to get property 'blog_name' of non-object

How do I fix this?

Here is the code in **app\Http\Controllers\siteUIcontroller.php**

```
public function index()
{
    return view('index')->with('blog_name' , Setting::first()->blog_name)
                        ->with('categories' , Category::take(5)->get() ) 
                        ->with('tags' , Tag::take(12)->get() ) 
                        ->with('first_post' , Post::orderBy('created_at','desc')->first())
                        ->with('second_post' , Post::orderBy('created_at','desc')->skip(1)->take(1)->get()->first())
                        ->with('third_post' , Post::orderBy('created_at','desc')->skip(2)->take(1)->get()->first()) 
                        ->with('fourth_post' , Post::orderBy('created_at','desc')->skip(3)->take(1)->get()->first())
                        ->with('ruby_on_rails',  Category::find(2) )
                        ->with('laravel',  Category::find(1) )
                        ->with('settings',  Setting::first() )
                        ->with('django_python',  Category::find(4) ) 
                         ;

}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Why are you using repeated `Category`, `Post`?

Comment: Ok i will try it

Comment: No it's not working

Comment: My bad, just make sure there actually is a Setting's object stored. Otherwise return a default value if you must when the returned value is null. If you use php 8 you could use the null safe operator to make sure you don't call a property on a null object [Null safe RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/nullsafe_operator)

Comment: Okay, I'll try to do it